# Django translate templatetag string parameters

Tags: django, gettext, django-templates

Is there an easy solution to mark string parameters of an `inclusion_tag` (or a templatetag in general) for translation? In this example i want to mark the second parameter for translation:

```
{% render_tile_section qs "Foo" %}
```

Using a inclusion_tag like this obviously doesn't work:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

@register.inclusion_tag('content/includes/tile_section.html')
def render_tile_section(qs, headline=''):
    return {'qs': qs,
            'headline': u'%s' % _(headline) if headline else ''}
```

My first idea was to subclass `inclusion_tag` and make it work like the `trans` tag for string parameters. But as far as i know Django's `makemessages` command will only evaluate `trans` and `blocktrans` in templates or i there a way to extend it? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functionality is already built into Django's templatetags. Totally missed this in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/i18n/#in-template-code):

```
{% some_special_tag _("Page not found") value|yesno:_("yes,no") %}
```